# CORS error in a local JSON with Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone (it's taking a while, though :P ) and I'm trying to load a local JSON from a subdirectory into my collection, but my browser inspector (chrome in this case) runs into a Cross Origin Request error, but I thought that the CORS errors happen when you ask for resources from other domains, I'm wrong?

Here is my code

```
var DirectoryItem = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Directory = Backbone.Collection.extend({    
    model: DirectoryItem,
    url: 'JSON/directory.json'
});

var directory = new Directory(); 
directory.fetch({
  success:function(){
      console.log('It worked!!');
    }
 });
```

Comment: it can also happen in you're making requests from http to https or vice versa, but i don't see how that could be the issue here.

Comment: Different ports also count as cross-domain

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, there is any way to solve it?

Comment: you can use chrome extension to allow cross origin policy. but it will work only for you ofc.

Comment: Trying to access files from file system will also cause security issues, which can be solved by serving the files via a web server